# Wrong keyboard Y-position

Tags: ios, swift

I add my CustomView in ViewController. I Use this method:

```
func showCreateProfileAlert() {
            let screenHeight = UIWindow().screen.bounds.height
            let screenWidth = UIWindow().screen.bounds.width

            //Alert
            let alert = CreateNewJobProfile.instanceFromNib()
            let height = (self.view.bounds.height + 94) - self.view.bounds.height
            let frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: height, width: self.view.bounds.width - 16, height: 200)
            alert.frame = frame
            self.createProfileView = alert

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.view.addSubview(alert)
            }
    }
```

CustomView has UIImageView with Tap gesture and UITextField. Gesture calling method for present modal UIImageViewController:

```
func photoFromLibrary() {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)   
    }
```

Keyboard has right position on bottom screen.
If dismiss UIImagePickerController, keyboard has wrong Y-Position.

UIImagePickerController delegate method:

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
           //Create and show alert again
           self.showCreateProfileAlert()
        })
    }
```

This top screen, when keyboard hided:

[image]

Keyboard frame when show:
(-207.0, -271.0, 414.0, 271.0)

**UPDATE**

I created simple UIViewController with UIImageView and UITextfield and got this bug again.
I just present modal UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Application Language:

```
Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... or press cmd + Y.
```

Comment: I have this bug on device and simulator.